# Rails Controller include record and it's children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app, I would like to create a list view that includes a master record and it's children.

Workorder Model:

```
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Workorder", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Workorder", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
```

This is my attempt:

```
  def index17
    @workorder = params[:workorder_id]
    @workorders =  Workorder.find(@workorder)
    @workorders = @workorders + Workorder.find(@workorder).children    
  end
```

I'm trying to make the master as the first record and then all of it's children.

Rails doesn't like the "+":

```
undefined method `+' for #<Workorder:0x007fefcddf85f8>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def index17
  @workorder_id = params[:workorder_id]
  @workorder =  Workorder.find(@workorder_id)
  @workorders = [@workorder, @workorder.children].flatten
end
```

This will create a flat list, with the parent first, followed by its children.

Alternatively, if you'd like to try some Rails / SQL magic, you can order by the `parent_id` column, like so:

```
@workorders = Workorder.where("parent_id = ? OR (parent_id IS NULL AND id = ?)", params[:workorder_id], params[:workorder_id]).order(:parent_id)
```

Consequently, the parent will be on top (because the null column is ordered first, followed by each of its children. The advantage this version has is that it is one less query on the database, and at least one less line of code; both of which are always nice.

Comment: That worked - except changed to `@workorder =  Workorder.find(@workorder)` - Thanks!

Comment: @Reddirt I changed the name of the original variables to make it clearer which variable was which. I would actually recommend keeping it closer to what I have for that reason (though its up to you). Also, check out my alternative in the update, see if that works too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that it doesn't like it, it's that `@workorders` is a instance of `Workorder` which doesn't have that method. You can use an array and then concat the children:

```
@parent = Workorder.find(params[:workorder_id])
@workorders = []
@workorders << @parent
@workorders.concat @parent.children # it's now [@parent, children1, children2 ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always do something like 
`@workorders.children.unshift(@workorders)`
to prepend to the front of the array as well.

Answer (score 0):

When giving `find` a single value, it returns a single record - not a collection. So `@workorders =  Workorder.find(@workorder)` gives you a single record, which doesn't have a `+` method. To force `find` to return a collection, give it an array:

```
def index17
  @workorder = params[:workorder_id]
  @workorders =  Workorder.find([@workorder])
  @workorders = @workorders + @workorders.first.children    
end
```

This works find :)